# Iterate over nested Map terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a variable which is a nested loop that looks like this:

```
variable "backup_times" {
  default     = {
    "namespace1" = {
      "four-hour" = "10 */4 * * *",
      "daily" = "12 10 * * *",
      "weekly" = "10 * * * */7"
      },
      "namespace2" = {
      "four-hour" = "20 */4 * * *",
      "daily" = "12 20 * * *",
      "weekly" = "20 * * * */7"
      }
    }
}
```

I also have another list variable of namesapces:

```
backup_namespaces = ["namespace1", "namespace2"]
```

I want to generate a custom map  using a for loop that iterates through each namespace name and then parses in the 3 different backup schedules.

so far I have:

```
for name in var.backup_namespaces:
      {
      for schedule, time in var.backup_times[name]:
        "${name}-${schedule}-backup" => {
          schedule = "${var.backup_times[name]}" 
          template = {
            includeClusterResources = true
            includedNamespaces      = [name]
            includedResources       = ["*"]
            storageLocation         = "aws"
            snapshotVolumes         = true


}
```

I want to get something that looks like this:

```
${namespace1}-${four-hour}-backup" = {
          schedule = "10 */4 * * *" 
          template = {
            includeClusterResources = true
            includedNamespaces      = [namespace1]
            includedResources       = ["*"]
            storageLocation         = "aws"
            snapshotVolumes         = true

},
${namespace1}-${daily}-backup" = {
          schedule = "12 10 * * *" 
          template = {
            includeClusterResources = true
            includedNamespaces      = [namespace1]
            includedResources       = ["*"]
            storageLocation         = "aws"
            snapshotVolumes         = true
},
${namespace1}-${weekly}-backup" = {
          schedule = "10 * * * */7" 
          template = {
            includeClusterResources = true
            includedNamespaces      = [namespace1]
            includedResources       = ["*"]
            storageLocation         = "aws"
            snapshotVolumes         = true
}},
${namespace2}-${4hour}-backup" = {
          schedule = "20 */4 * * *" 
          template = {
            includeClusterResources = true
            includedNamespaces      = [namespace2]
            includedResources       = ["*"]
            storageLocation         = "aws"
            snapshotVolumes         = true
},
${namespace2}-${daily}-backup" = {
          schedule = "12 20 * * *" 
          template = {
            includeClusterResources = true
            includedNamespaces      = [namespace2]
            includedResources       = ["*"]
            storageLocation         = "aws"
            snapshotVolumes         = true
},
${namespace2}-${weekly}-backup" = {
          schedule = "20 * * * */7" 
          template = {
            includeClusterResources = true
            includedNamespaces      = [namespace2]
            includedResources       = ["*"]
            storageLocation         = "aws"
            snapshotVolumes         = true
}}
```

When I try the above for loop I get this error:

var.backup_times is object with 2 attributes

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: string
required.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What would happen if you were to drop the `[name]` from referencing the variable, i.e., `for schedule, time in var.backup_times`?

Comment: It seems to work but the output is wrong and messes things up. @MarkoE I've made some edit to my code - I forgot to mention I have another array called ```backup_namespaces = ["namespace1", "namespace2"]
```

Comment: @MarkoE This is embarrassing but it seems like there was a small typo the above code works fine with [name] thanks for your help